# MySQL Multiple condition on multiple columns in one case

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is that possible to get multiple condition on multiple columns in one case i tried using this.. it is not creating any error but result is not correct. should i use IF else?

```
SELECT 
  p.name,
  p.is_deleted,
( CASE WHEN pro.is_active = 1 THEN 'Active'
       WHEN pro.is_del = 1 THEN 'Not Active-Promotion Deleted'
       WHEN p.is_active = 0 THEN 'Not Active-Page Inactive'
       WHEN p.is_deleted = 1 THEN 'Not Active-Page Deleted'
  END) AS 'Status'
FROM
  page_promotions pro 
  INNER JOIN pages p 
    ON pro.page_id = p.pages_id
```

[Expected and Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHsqi.jpg)

Comment: Not correct? Tell us more.

Comment: Add the wrong output and the expected output please

Comment: Together with the sample table data used.

Comment: You need to consider the fact that CASE statements evaluate from first to last. As soon as a case is met, the statement will end. You may need to add additional clauses to each case, or reorder them, to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @jarlh image attached

Comment: @rbr94 image attached

Comment: @JohnHC perfect answer.. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE statements evaluate from first to last. As soon as a case is met, the statement will end. You may need to add additional clauses to each case, or reorder them, to achieve the desired result.

This is the behaviour of SQL:

- A CASE expression evaluates to the first true condition as soon as the case meet the condition it ends.
- If there is no true condition, it evaluates to the ELSE part.
- If there is no true condition and no ELSE part, it evaluates to NULL

Add some aditional conditions to every case or reorder it to get the proper result

in your case to get desire output

```
SELECT 
  p.name,
  p.is_deleted,
( CASE  WHEN p.is_active = 0 THEN 'Not Active-Page Inactive'
        WHEN p.is_deleted = 1 THEN 'Not Active-Page Deleted'
        WHEN pro.is_del = 1 THEN 'Not Active-Promotion Deleted'
        WHEN pro.is_active = 1 THEN 'Active'
  END) AS 'Status'
FROM
  page_promotions pro 
  INNER JOIN pages p 
    ON pro.page_id = p.pages_id
```